# How to set an overdraft limit

Tags: java

what I am trying to do is set a overdraft limit i.e. -150 the user cannot withdraw any further if their balance is -150. My code is below:

**Withdraw Method**

```
public void Withdraw(double amount){


    if (amount + 5 > balance ){ //If amount and transaction fee is greater than balance then apply for overdraft
        System.out.println("Insufficent funds");
        System.out.println("Would you like to apply for an ovedraft?");
        System.out.println("1:Yes");
        System.out.println("2:No, return me back to menus");
        Choice = Option.nextLine();
        if (Choice.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
         if((balance = balance - amount+5)<=-150){   //If balance is grater than 150 , apply for overdraft
             System.out.println("You have exceeded your Overdraft Limit, you will now be returned back to the menus");
         return;

        }
        else{ //if not exceeding bank balance
            balance -= amount + 5; 
            System.out.println("You have withdrawen £" + amount);
            System.err.println("You now have a balance of £" +balance);
            return; 
        }
    }
}

}
```

They are all in the Same class which is "Account", what happens now is that the message does occur-("You have exceeded your Overdraft Limit, you will now be returned back to the menus") and returns back to the menus but when I go to check the balance the money is still deducted and displays a balance which goes over -150 eg. -190 how can I make it that -150 is the limit and not deduct anymore than that. Hope the question was understood.

Comment: Stack Overflow markdown interprets your variables as classes cause you write them with a capital letter. Ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
if ((balance = balance - amount + 5) <= -150) {
```

The critical thing here is that `=`. That is assigtning the new amount **before** the check.

Something like this may avoid the problem.

```
    if (balance - amount - 5 < 0) {
        System.out.println("Insufficent funds");
        System.out.println("Would you like to apply for an ovedraft?");
        System.out.println("1:Yes");
        System.out.println("2:No, return me back to menus");
        Choice = Option.nextLine();
        if (Choice.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            if (balance - amount - 5 <= -150) {
                System.out.println("You have exceeded your Overdraft Limit, you will now be returned back to the menus");
            } else { //if not exceeding bank balance
                balance -= amount + 5;
                System.out.println("You have withdrawen £" + amount);
                System.err.println("You now have a balance of £" + balance);
            }
```

Notice the more explicit calculations (`if (balance - amount - 5 <= -150)`) that dry-run the maths and comparison using `<= 0`. This is gneerally easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

`if((balance = balance - amount+5)<=-150)` is your issue. First of all, you have not written `amount+5` inside parentheses, so it should be `amount-5` instead.

Secondly, you are actually changing your balance here (`=` is the assigning operator). You have also written `<=` instead of `<`. What you instead should write is the following:

`if(balance-(amount+5) < -150)`

Answer (score 0):

additional to all the answer above I will add this:

if I have **1$** and I make a overdraft of **50$**  then my account can be at

> 1$-55$ =-54$

but with this condition here is not possible

```
if (amount + FEES > balance) { // If amount and transaction fee is greater than balance then apply for overdraft
System.out.println("Insufficent funds");
```